# What Are All of the Changes Race Can Make to a Character?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, races

In D&D 3.5e, what are all the changes that a race can make to a character? e.g., base attributes change for some races, but humans just give a bonus feat, and some races can add natural armor or other bonuses.

I'm designing a character organizer—mostly just for experience's sake—and I'm trying to figure out how best to represent a race programmatically, so that custom races can be constructed.

**Details**

I'm not looking for specifics, like a Dwarf gets +2 CON and -2 CHA, I'm looking for a list of effects, such as "any race can potentially affect attributes, skills, feats, etc..."

I also could just go through the books and write this all down, but my question is more systematic/thematic: what could any race, even one that another GM created, possible change about a character.

Comment: I think there is a pretty short answer possible here, "anything". If you can find an attribute a character has, there's most likely some race out there that changes it, which makes listing them all waaay too broad.

Comment: so are you looking for a list of all the variables your Race method is going to have to access?

Comment: As indicated by my answer, this question desperately needs some narrowing down. At a bare minimum, you should probably specify – assuming I’ve guessed your intent correctly – that you’re looking for LA +0, playable-from-1st races, since the distinction between “race” and “playable creature” is... well, there actually isn’t one, in the rules, the terms are used interchangeably. But even with that change, I just don’t think there is – or can be – an answer to that question, because the possibilities are much too diverse and can only be judged on a case-by-case basis.

Answer (score 1):

Literally anything. Black ethergaunts are a playable “race” that start with 16 HD, numerous powerful unique abilities, and to top it off, the spellcasting of a 17th-level wizard.

Most dragons out there are playable, too, what with their hearty defenses, innate spellcasting, and iconic breath weapons. A war wyrm (using the alternate draconic features from *Dragons of Eberron*) can even swap the spellcasting for initiating martial maneuvers from *Tome of Battle* (making it one of only two books, to my knowledge, that reference *Tome of Battle* outside itself).

Angels, devils, and demons are playable, and again come with innate spellcasting and lots of other neat features.

The marrulurk from *Sandstorm* gets the assassin’s death attack and a nauseating breath weapon, not to mention innate Sneak Attack and several useful feats.

There is nothing that seems to be beyond the possibility of races. Once racial hit dice and level adjustment are included, racial features can – and indeed, must, if they are to actually be viable in play – do anything and everything that class levels can.

Comment: Is there any theoretical reason that any (one) thing is out of the reach of even LA+0? The evidence from various higher LA examples paints a dire picture, but if a greater LA than 0 isn't even necessary for an “potentially anything” answer, that's even more compelling.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Ultimately, I’d say yes – even if you saddled some race with tons and tons of drawbacks to make up for whatever thing you end up getting that would normally be too good, I would call that bad design and not in keeping with the way the game is written (it would skew the character in inappropriate ways). So it’s too strong a statement for LA +0. But at the same time, it’s probably impossible to accurately draw the line, and definitely impossible to produce a comprehensive list.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, a race can give absolutely anything. Given the context of your question though, it sounds like what you really want to know is "What effects are so commonly associated with race that it would be worth making them part of a data structure?"

- All races have a size
- All races have an LA (sometimes +0)
- All races should have ages (often unlisted)
- All races have natural attacks of some sort
- All races have language choices
- Most races adjust stats
- Most races have a favored class
- Many races have a natural armor bonus
- Many races adjust skills

If you have fields for those, you should be okay covering the rest as text blobs.